# Why won't this paragraph line up correctly between the quotes?

Tags: css

I'm having trouble keeping the paragraph square between the quote marks. In firefox the last line between the quotes sticks out too far to the left. The image is what I would like it to look like.

[image]

http://jsbin.com/elohej  <-This shows the problem exactly in firefox.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
/* Block Quote*/
#bqstyle{
    width: 650px;
    margin:30px 0 0 230px;
    border: solid 1px #000;

}

#bqstyle blockquote{
    font-size:24px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0 25px 50px 0;

}

.bqstart {
     float: left;
     font-size: 700%;
     color: #605f5f;
     height:25px;
     margin-top: -40px;
     padding-right: 5px;
     padding-bottom: 100px;
 }



 .bqend {
     float: right;
     font-size: 700%;
     color: #605f5f;
     height: 35px;
     margin-top: -35px;
     margin-right:-40px;
 }

/* END Block Quote*/
</style>


</head>

<div id="bqstyle">
<blockquote><p><span class="bqstart">&#8220;</span>Frank is the best. I take my Z to Hill&#8217;s for all my maintenance and car needs, and I&#8217;ll never take it to the dealership again. Better service. Better prices. <span class="bqend">&#8221;</span></p></blockquote>
</div>
<p> Test Paragraph Test ParagraphTest ParagraphTest ParagraphTest ParagraphTest ParagraphTest ParagraphTest ParagraphTest ParagraphTest ParagraphTest ParagraphTest ParagraphTest ParagraphTest ParagraphTest Paragraph</p>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please make a jsfiddle or jsbin and post a link?

Comment: Can you show an image of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Jsbin shows the problem. http://jsbin.com/elohej

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you mean by _"having trouble keeping the paragraph square between the quote marks"_.  It's between the quotes so what does "square" have to do with it?  And your image, your jsFiddle and your jsBin show three different results using just one browser.

Comment: The image is what I would like it to look like. In firefox the the last sentence doesn't line up with the rest of the paragraph.

Comment: Describe the meaning of _"does not line up"_.  Too high, too low, too far to the left, the right, what?  The quality of an answer will always reflect the quality of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by absolutely positionning your opening quote instead of floating it, and adding padding-left on your p tag.

```
blockquote p {
     padding-left: 80px;
     position: relative;
}

.bqstart {
     font-size: 700%;
     color: #605f5f;
     height:25px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
 }
```